# Mirror modifier not working

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I'm hoping someone can help here - When I try to mirror the saucer, the window cutouts around the rim, are not applied to the mirror. However, two further window cut outs (Not visible here)  in the top of the saucer do appear correctly in the mirrored image.
[image: Before Mirror]

[image: After Mirror]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6698" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6698/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, the windows that we can see on your first picture on the left are another object, so it won't be affected by the Mirror modifier. Also, apply the rotation of your object so that the Mirror axis are correct, and maybe put the Edge Split below the Mirror

Comment: They are another object - Glass, but the hull has already had the cutouts for the windows applied, so I expected that the cutouts should be shown in the mirrored version. I'm sorry but I'm a newbie!

Comment: Also it looks like you've build your spaceship with different parts that have thickness, are you sure it is useful to have different parts, and most of all, is the thickness useful? If you keep it at least make sure that there is no face at the mirror joint otherwise it may create artefact. And you have a lot of faces, do you need so many? Why not much less and use a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: Hi Moonboots. Thank you for your input, but as I explained I am new to this and it's a steep learning curve! I am just following a tutorial and the way it has been tackled is the path I am following. I obviously have a lot to learn regarding Subdivision Surface Modifiers and the like. I shall press on. At least it's fun!